# Github pages redirect non www (root domain) to www subdomain

Tags: redirect, jekyll, github-pages, no-www

I have build a website for github pages with jekyll. I setted it up and everything seems to be fine, and my custom domain [www.domain.tld](http://www.domain.tld) is working.
But when I enter domain.tld in the browser, it loads for an infinite time. Now I want to redirect the-non www-URL to the www-URL but since I don't have a editable htacces File on Github pages I don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 8):

### There is a generic method to do that.

For example, my github repo is: [wpfgeek.github.io](https://github.com/wpfgeek/wpfgeek.github.io).

### 1. Edit CNAME file in your repository

**[wpfgeek.github.io](https://github.com/wpfgeek/wpfgeek.github.io)**/**CNAME**

```
www.geekzl.com
```

### 2. Enable the https in the settings of the repo

Go to the setting page of the github repo, find the `Enforce HTTPS` under "Github pages", then tick the checkbox before `Enforce HTTPS`.

[image: geekcl.com - Enable the https]

### 3. Update DNS Settings in DNS provider

Open DNS provider, add two records like below:

```
---------------------------------------------
| Record | Record Type | Value              |
| ------ | ----------- | ------------------ |
| @      | A           | 185.199.108.153    |
| ------ | ----------- | ------------------ |
| www    | CNAME       | wpfgeek.github.io. |
```

Then the site https://geekzl.com and http://geekzl.com will be redirected to https://www.geekzl.com successfully.

You can replace `www.geekzl.com` to your domain with the prefix `www`, then replace the CNAME record of `wpfgeek.github.io` to your repo name.

May it be helpful for you, just enjoy!

Comment: I noticed that your CNAME changed to web.geekzl.com, did the other configuration steps change?

Comment: @Julio The method in this answer is still valid. Currently this site changed because of my personal needs, it is not deployed in github.io now.

Comment: The same should work for subdomains, but you should define both as CNAME record types pointing to USERNAME.github.io

Comment: @BravoYeung What if I want to access the site at [example.com](https://example.com) and redirect [www.example.com](https://www.example.com) to [example.com](https://example.com)?

Comment: For anyone struggling with a missing SSL certificate on the root domain: 

I Followed the instructions above for https://www.flyde.dev, but it ended in an SSL  
error as "flyde.dev" had no certificate.

To fix that, I changed the domain on Github's end to be "flyde.dev", which triggered an SSL certificate creation, and then switched back to "www." and everything is working now!

Answer (score 4):

It depends on the domain hosting service you bought your custom domain from (Google Domains, Domain.com, etc...). You'll have to look in the settings and try to find something like "subdomain forwarding" or "domain forwarding". The wording depends on each service.

The service should have a settings that allow you to forward `nikurasu.xyz` to `www.nikurasu.xyz` with settings like `Temporary redirect (302)`, `path forwarding`, `Enable SSL`. These are examples from Google Domains, which is my hosting service.

Ultimately, the `www` forwarding is all done with the domain hosting service and has nothing to do with your GitHub repo or GitHub settings.

Answer (score 1):

Further to @DC.Azndj answer, and applicable only to Google Domains.

The option is in Website menu and not in DNS. This is somewhat confusing if you are familiar with DNS.

Use the option "Add a forwarding address".

By default Google adds two names **example.com** and **www.example.com**. If you are forwarding within the same domain, from **example.com** to **www.example.com**, you need to edit and remove **www** entry.

In advanced options you can enable forwarding both SSL and non-SSL ports.

There are few other useful options like path forwarding etc.